# TabSpec SetContent to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I am using TabHost inside Fragment to create tabs.  The problem I run into is TabSpec's `setContent()`.  I need to set it so that it nests another fragment under the `<FrameLayout>`.

Do I uses `getChildFragmentManager()` to do this?  How do I do so?

Xml Layout:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_weight="0"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
            />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/following"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/you"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment class:

```
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
private static final String FOLLOWING_SPEC = "following";
private static final String YOU_SPEC = "you";

private TabHost tabHost;

public ActivityFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);

    tabHost = (TabHost)view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec followingSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(FOLLOWING_SPEC);
    followingSpec.setIndicator("Following");
    followingSpec.setContent(); // <===Need to set content to fragment

    TabHost.TabSpec youSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(YOU_SPEC);
    youSpec.setIndicator("You");

    tabHost.addTab(followingSpec);
    tabHost.addTab(youSpec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String s) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer.  I was mixing android's TabHost with the support library's FragmentTabHost.  Two different things!

```
public class ActivityFragment extends Fragment implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener {
private static final String FOLLOWING_SPEC = "following";
private static final String YOU_SPEC = "you";

private FragmentTabHost tabHost;

public ActivityFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_activity, container, false);

    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost)view.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(FOLLOWING_SPEC).setIndicator("Following"), FollowingActivityFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(YOU_SPEC).setIndicator("You"), YouActivityFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    return view;
}



 @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String s) {

    }
}
```